# Maven наследование одного модуля от другого

Tags: java, spring, maven, модули, function-overloading

Есть модуль web он работает,всё запускается... Создал второй модуль web-new В идеале хочу сделать его наследником от просто web и например переписать одну страницу или в будущем класс итп. Как такое можно реализовать?
Для примера создал репозиторий https://github.com/Piom/level_app

Comment: А какую цель вы этим преследуете или, иначе говоря, какую задачу пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Есть 2 веб модуля, различается по штатам, один модуль почти полностью копирует другой, но на на веб морде есть некоторые изменений.. потом этих модулей будет не 2 а 5.. и грубо есть базовая часть, а под каждый штат идет кастомизация.

Answer (score 1):

В основном pom.xml описываете модули :

```
<modules>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>web-new</module>
</modules>
```

Затем при билде включаем или переопределяем файлы или пакеты из web, например как это выглядело у меня:

```
<build>
    <finalName>level_app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>ru.piom.mvc.level</groupId>
                        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>пример/пути/файл.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <packagingExcludes>**/address/**/*.*</packagingExcludes>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Вот этот файл который заэксклюдили из web, будет браться из web-new при его наличии.
В любом случаем посмотрите в сторону build>configeration>overlays